# DNS resolution Issue nslookup works, but web/ping doesn't

Tags: windows, dns

I've got a computer having DNS problems with one address only, "microsoftonline.com".
Ping doesnt resolve IP but nslookup does correctly. It works from other machines. It is WinXP with no proxies

I have tried google's DNS servers with no avail. Any ideas?

The ping error is "Ping request could not find host...."

Answer (score 8):

Check your `hosts` file, although I don't think that's likely to be the cause.

Disable the XP firewall and test.

Try `net stop dnscache` then `net start dnscache`.  This seems to do something that `ipconfig /flushdns` doesn't, IMX.

Delete the arp cache: `netsh interface ip delete arpcache`

Check your routing table: `route print`

Answer (score 3):

Try flushing your DNS cache on the machine by running this from the command line:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. I've also tried repairing the network connection and restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Before going crazy resetting everything, let's try some simpler tests:

- Can you `ping google.com`?
- Can you ping google DNS: `ping 8.8.4.4` ?
- Do you have multiple IPs/Default gateways that may be conflicting ( output from: `ipconfig /all`)
- Are you using both IPv6 and IPv4 on your network?
- Can you verify the following services are running: `DNS Client` `Network Location Awareness` `Remote Procedure Call (RPC)` ? (open task manager, under services tab)
- Are you running a firewall?
- What is the output of `ping -a 64.4.6.100` ? (this is the IP of microsoftonline.com)

Overall, this sounds like it could be a number of things including DNS hijacking, corrupt network somewhere, or something else strange with Windows. One post I found fixed the same issue with Windows XP by uninstalling and re-installing SP3 (weird).