# nslookup on XP resolves to address, but ping can't find host

Tags: windows-xp, dns

I don't know Windows very well.  This is Win XP SP3.  nslookup resolves hostname fine, but ping (and other DNS-users on the machine like Chrome) cannot resolve the same hostname.  ping works fine with explicit IP address.

Is this a bug in XP?

```
C:\>nslookup blade.haq.loc
Server:  dns.haq.loc
Address:  10.10.10.16

Name:    blade.haq.loc
Address:  10.10.10.22


C:\>ping blade.haq.loc
Ping request could not find host blade.haq.loc. Please check the name and try ag
ain.

C:\>ping 10.10.10.22

Pinging 10.10.10.22 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 10.10.10.22: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.10.10.22: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.10.10.22: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is 'ping' unable to resolve a name when 'nslookup' works fine?](http://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cache:

in `cmd.exe`:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

If that doesnt resolve the problem, then there could be a possible conflict with your DNS server.

So if it doesnt work,

- Go into "Network and Sharing Center"
- Open up the connection that you are using
- Go to Properties
- Look for the IPv4 Address
- And assign it a specific DNS server, try using Google's Public DNS servers "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4"