# Why do I need to add a period after hostname in order to get DNS resolution to work?

Tags: windows, networking, dns

```
C:\Users\david>nslookup home-pi3
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    home-pi3
Address:  192.168.1.81


C:\Users\david>ping home-pi3
Ping request could not find host home-pi3. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\david>ping home-pi3.

Pinging home-pi3 [192.168.1.81] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.81: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.81: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
```

Comment: When you put a dot, you are saying the hostname is fully qualified, otherwise it will add your DNS suffix.  What is doing the resolution?  DNS or a hostfile?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using DNS for resolution. How do I know what my DNS suffix is? I checked my Advanced TCP/IP settings and there's no DNS suffix set there. This computer is not part of any AD domain.

Comment: The same question was asked the same day, and is here: https://superuser.com/questions/1078467/why-cannot-i-ping-computer-name-without-dot/1078468

Comment: If you want to just use `home-pi3` and not `home-pi3.` then please see [my answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1257512/157461).