# Windows 8/10 DNS issues browser - ping - nslookup

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, browser, ping

I know it has been asked before, but to date, I've not been able to find a final working solution (which keeps working) because on very rare occasions, it all works, but after a reboot it is back to this.

**The situation:**

Lab environment, subnet x.x.x.0/24 
Lab DNS servers : 
x.x.x.60 (windows server, has dns records for local machines, only listening on ipv4, does not forward to the outside world, that is where the 2nd DNS server comes in) 
x.x.x.15 (dns cache & forwarder to internet) 
internal domain : labnet.intra.

a few hosts, who have their dns record in the x.x.x.60, 
example : webserver hostname app05 has ip x.x.x.32

**Windows 8 machine in the same subnet, not in an AD domain, with** only 1 active LAN connection, with
chrome, ff, IE11. (Also installed Norton Security, Malwarebytes, which could have an impact to network services, however, during the tests below, they were operating normally, so I doubt they would have much impact on this issue). Hosts file is empty.

the ping test is always done 2 times : one with hostname and one with the fqdn of the host app05.labnet.intra (never makes a difference in results, both work or both don't work)

nslookup by default queries the .60 (which is good)

**TEST 1 : starting point**

ping to app05 : not found

nslookup to app05 : found with correct ip

ANY browser to app05 : not found

**TEST 1a : the usual start : **
ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /registerdns

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

netsh winsock reset catalog

netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log

*Results :* does not make a difference

ping to app05 : not found

nslookup to app05 : found with correct ip

ANY browser to app05 : not found

**TEST 2 : disable the windows DNSClient service**

*Results :*

ping to app05 : ok

nslookup to app05 : ok

FF browser to app05 : ok

CHROME browser to app05 : ok

IE 11 : app05 seems to load now, BUT ... actually IE now has even more strange or erratic behavior : at this moment internet website cannot be displayed, if I try superuser.com (which was opened before) at this moment, I see in the statusbar "waiting for response from superuser.com" but then I get a "page cannot not be displayed" error. So IE does not seem to want to use the specified DNS servers?

**TEST 3 : enabled DNSClient service again**

*Results :*

ping to app05 : ok

nslookup to app05 : ok

ANY browser to app05 : ok

HOWEVER : after a few minutes it is back to before:

ping to app05 : not ok

nslookup to app05 : ok

ANY browser to app05 : not ok

**TEST 4 : turned off IPv6 on all interfaces (connected or not)**

*Results :* at first I had a "yes, it works...."

ping to app05 : ok

nslookup to app05 : ok

ANY browser to app05 : ok

HOWEVER : after a few minutes it is back to before:

ping to app05 : not ok

nslookup to app05 : ok

ANY browser to app05 : not ok

So basically : nslookup always works correctly

Turning off DNSClient service would be the good solution, if it wasn't for IE no longer working. If I could solve the issue with IE11 when the DNSClient service is disabled, I probably would be happy. As that is the most strange of this all. IT seems IE cannot work without the DNSClient service?

The most frustrating : it worked for weeks, today after a reboot, I'm back to this state of having the DNS resolution problem. Nothing was changed on the PC

Anyone any extra ideas, or a fresh pair of eyes to look at this?

Comment: Have you seen this (admittedly weird!) answer: https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine/1257512#1257512

Comment: Try to disable 'Enhanced Protected Mode' in IE's advanced settings while turning off the DNSClient service. It might also be better to avoid Modern IE or any Modern app.

Comment: @djsmiley2k : I saw that before, tried it, but does not make a difference. The symptoms I have are a bit different then in that case. It also probably does not make sense, because it also affects external websites.

Comment: @harrymc : I just tried it, and at first sight that seems to work ! Thanks.

Comment: I have added an answer. If this works for you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable 'Enhanced Protected Mode' in IE's Advanced settings,
as it needs the DNSClient service for some unknown implementation reason.

The DNSClient service is also required for Modern IE and some other Modern apps.
You will need to use the desktop version of IE if this service is disabled.