# On my Mac, I can "nsloookup hostname" but I can't ping it?

Tags: dns, ping

Mac OS Ventura 13.3.1

I've read other questions regarding "Can ping IP but not hostname" and the answers are all related to the DNS. In my case I believe my DNS is set up correctly. Also, I'm using my router's wired connection instead of WiFi.

**NOTE**: The problem only occurs on my company's internal (to the VPN) servers. I can ping external servers, e.g., [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

I've flushed the DNS cache

```
% sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I'm going through my company's VPN, and in my network interface settings, I have the DNS servers set up the my IT department gave me. I can do this

```
% nslookup dc1-main.company.com
Server:     10.227.10.4
Address:    10.227.10.4#53

Name:   dc1-main.company.com
Address: 10.227.25.17
```

I can then do

```
% ping 10.227.25.17
PING 10.227.25.17 (10.227.25.17): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.227.25.17: icmp_seq=0 ttl=125 time=41.206 ms
64 bytes from 10.227.25.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=125 time=41.698 ms
64 bytes from 10.227.25.17: icmp_seq=2 ttl=125 time=41.714 ms
^C
--- 10.227.25.17 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 41.206/41.539/41.714/0.236 ms
```

But this fails

```
% ping dc1-main.company.com
ping: cannot resolve dc1-main.company.com: Unknown host
```

Here's the traceroute. For the IP, the hop from #4 to #64 was just `* * *`

```
% traceroute 10.227.25.17 
traceroute to 10.227.25.17 (10.227.25.17), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.40.14 (192.168.40.14)  25.321 ms  24.286 ms  24.585 ms
 2  172.16.25.1 (172.16.25.1)  24.737 ms  24.578 ms  25.052 ms
 3  192.168.150.20 (192.168.150.20)  44.081 ms  44.232 ms  43.149 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
...
64  * * *


% traceroute dc1-main.company.com
traceroute: unknown host dc1-main.company.com
```

Why is this? TIA!

I see [Why is 'ping' unable to resolve a name when 'nslookup' works fine?](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine) but it relates to Windows and the recommendations don't makes sense for the Mac.

**UPDATE**
Someone requested this info

```
% nslookup -q=AAAA dc1-main.company.com
Server:     10.227.10.4
Address:    10.227.10.4#53

*** Can't find dc1-main.company.com: No answer
```

Comment: The gist of the linked question is still the same on macOS or Linux: `nslookup` does not resolve names like `ping` (or anything else, really) does.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Can you post the output of 

    traceroute 10.227.25.17

and

    traceroute dc1-main.company.com

Comment: @DanielB, yes I understand. The answers offered in the linked question aren't pertinent to me so I posted a separate one.

Comment: @Richie086 I'll update the post post with the `traceroutes` shortly.

Comment: Can you `nslookup -q=AAAA` the domain name?

Comment: @user1686 I updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After wasting *hours* on this problem, I finally found the fix. My DHCP server hands out an internal DNS first, then an external as a secondary. That external points to Google's 8.8.8.8.

e.g.:

```
10.0.1.232
10.0.2.232
8.8.8.8
```

I removed 8.8.8.8 from my DHCP assigned DNS server list et voila, I am now able to ping, ssh, traceroute, etc. internal resources. It appears that Apple decided to block non-DNSSEC systems when one that uses DNSSEC is in the list. DNSSEC, or Domain Name System Security Extensions, is a set of extensions to DNS that provides authentication of DNS data. So our internal DNS server (which doesn't really need DNSSEC) was not being queried because 8.8.8.8 naturally does use it. No idea why Apple would consider this a security concern.

This works:

```
10.0.1.232
10.0.2.232
```

Then my internal DNS server just sends unknowns to 8.8.8.8 instead of the client systems.

Comment: This fixed my issues with `git pull`, `ping github.com`, `ping google.com` etc. Something like `ping 1.1.1.1` worked, but only because I was bypassing the DNS resolution, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem for resolving hostnames for your internal domain, you can create a directory `/etc/resolver`. Then create a file named for each domain where you wish to specify a specific nameserver. For example:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/resolver
sudo chmod 755 /etc/resolver
sudo vi /etc/resolver/mydomain.example.com
sudo chmod 644 /etc/resolver/mydomain.example.com
```

Where the content of `mydomain.example.com` is:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.123
```

And where `10.0.0.123` is the IP address of the nameserver to be used for domain `mydomain.example.com`.

If you have multiple internal domains, create multiple such files.

This technique appears to supercede the list of domain servers returned via DHCP.