# "No internet" after a Windows update, apparently unfixable. Anybody on the planet who can find its root-cause?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

About 10 days ago, a colleague brought me his laptop due to a "no internet" problem. It's an Asus with Windows 11 Home on it. 22H2 was the version when the problem occurred.
That happened a few days before, after a round of Windows updates. But he admitted it had been quite a long time he didn't run updates on that laptop (not knowingly at least).

**Long story short**: It does connect to the internet (I can ping external websites in CMD by IP address), but it cannot surf the web (neither in any browser, nor even by pinging websites in CMD via names [but nslookup does work!].

Believe me if I said that I tried EVERYTHING.
Last week, I even re-installed Windows 11 on top of it (keep apps and files), but it didn't help. I also chatted online with Microsoft support.

I suspect it's a bug in one of the updates. The bug only affects the DNS capabilities when connected via WiFi (any WiFi, even a different external USB WiFi network adapter). When hardwired via Ethernet, everything works perfectly.

I suspect the in-place Windows (re)installation didn't help because, sadly, one can only download the Windows 11 23H2 ISO now, which obviously must include the set of updates of 22H2 that broke the internet here. So, when I re-instlled Windows, I ended up installing 23H2.

Oddly (hint here), the WiFi network exhibits intermittent hiccups (from showing the globe to the signal bars, but only 'apparently', as internet remains not available all the time when on WiFi).

The hardware works great: if booted from a Linux drive, it works perfectly and immediately. Also, as I said, I tried a different USB WiFi adapter.

I promise, whatever attempt, test, or possible solution you might be already thinking or might be going to think and/or to recommend, has already been tried and failed.

For your convenience, I will paste below here a sort of recap of (most of) the things that I did.

Whoever finds the solution and/or identifies the **specific** root-cause (affecting DLL, file, set of files, settings in a given INI file, registry key[s], whatever...), will have my most profound IT admiration forever. I will tell this story countless times whenever I'll have a chance, for the rest of my life, mentioning the Stack Exchange user who finally did it.

Thanks!

##### Recap of (most of) the attempted tests, assessments, and fixes:

- After a recent Windows update, which was run a few days ago, all of the sudden, the computer was cut off and unable to connect to the internet: "No internet".
- I tried 3 different ISPs, and the problem persisted
- I tried pinging external websites via IP addresses (for example, ping 8.8.8.8 for Google) under Command Prompt, and it pings perfectly, therefore, the computer, to some limited extent, does connect to the internet
- I tried pinging external websites under Command Prompt, but using the websites' names instead of IP addresses, the ping fails
- I tried 3 different browsers, the problem persists
- I tried to add a portable Firefox browser, the problem persists
- The browsers give the following error message (sometimes) when trying to load any website: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, which makes us think that everything points towards a DNS problem
- I tried Mobile hotspot with 3 different phones that we normally use to connect to the internet with several laptop computers (with which and they all work fine): the affected laptop fails on all the three of them.
- I tried to hardwire the affected computer via Ethernet cable and it works perfectly fine
- The problem occurs ONLY if connected to the internet via WiFi. On the other hand, if hardwired with an Ethernet cable, it works perfectly.
- I tried to upgrade the WiFi card drivers, trying different ones (directly from Intel, From Asus product support website, etc.), but the problem persists
- I deleted and reinstalled the WiFi card, the problem persists
- I disabled power saving in the WiFi card settings and we also disabled power saving for the PCI Express bus (which is where the affected laptop’s internal WiFi card is connected)
- **Important**: I tried a completely different WiFi adapter added on USB (the usb ports work perfectly with any other peripheral or USB memory drive), but the same problem persists.
- Yes, I tried several WiFi networks, the same problem persists
- The computer has always been protected by a professional corporate Syamantec Antivirus, but I also tried disabling it and disabling the Windows firewalls for a few moments, the problem persists
- I booted the affected computer via an updated antivirus' bootable USB rescue stick and run a full scan of the drive from there (before booting into Windows), to make a more thorough scan, no malware was found
- I tried the network reset several times, but it did not help.
- I tried reinstalling the drivers of the WiFi network card both with drivers taken from the computer manufacturer's website (Asus), under the specific computer product support page, and also taking the driver from Intel's website (Intel is the manufacturer of the internal WiFi network card). Both did not solve the issue.
- I must point out that I excluded the WiFi network card as cause of the problem. We can conclude that fairly certainly because I did this:

  1. I tried a completely different WiFi network card via USB port, and the same problem persists
  2. Also, when the problem occurs, if I PING external websites via IP address, the ping works. For example, I tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and it works fine under Command Prompt.
  3. Therefore, the connection works, the WiFi network card works and does connect to the internet.
- The problem occurs only when trying to resolve websites' names, for example trying to visit websites using web browsers or, in Command Prompt, if I try to ping external websites using the names instead of the IP addresses
  For example, in Command Prompt:
  PING 8.8.8.8 works fine
  PING google.com does not work
  therefore, there is connection, but it fails to resolve names. **Everything points to a DNS problem**.

Indeed, most of the times that web browsers fail to load any website (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Portable Firefox), they give the following error:
err_name_not_resolved

- which points towards a DNS problem
- But I've tried also all the DNS-troubleshooting procedures and they failed to fix the problem.
- I tried leaving the DNS settings to automatic
- I tried setting 3rd party DNSs (for example 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1), and it did not help
- I also tried uninstalling all the November updates that could be uninstalled, and it did not help. Perhaps, it was one of the updates that cannot be uninstalled, if any.
- I installed 23H2 on top of it (in-place Windows reinstallation), and it did not help again.
- That's why I decided to contact Microsoft Support, because we run out of bullets

**Microsoft asked**: Do you mean issue already started before installing 23H2 updates an hour ago?

- Correct

- Microsoft asked: Alright. Can we perform a system restore?

- there were no available restore points unfortunately.
- And today, earlier, I tried a Windows 11 repair-reinstall too, an in-place install. I reinstalled Windows 11 on top of the current one, keeping apps and files, but it did not help. That's when it updated to 23H2, when I downloaded the Windows 11 ISO from Microsoft and performed the reinstall on it.
- I have also Checked the Hosts File to map hostnames to IP addresses located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. And checked if there are any entries under the line 127.0.0.1 localhost. There are none.
- I have also tried booting in Safe Mode with Networking. Unfortunately, in safe mode, it only sees one virtual network adapter but it is unable to ‘see’ any WiFi network.
- I performed a Registry Edit: Some users have reported that editing a specific registry key resolved their issue. The key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\NlaSvc\\Parameters\\Internet` and the value to change is EnableActiveProbing. I made sure its value is 1 instead of 0. That didn’t help either.
- I would have liked trying to do an in-place upgrade of Windows 11 using an OLDER version of Windows 11, one that PRECEEDED the problem that occurred a few days ago. But I couldn't find any. On Microsoft, I could only download the 23H2 ISO
- I have already removed software most recently installed
- I have already tried temporarily disabling both the antivirus and Windows Firewall
- I have already installed the most recent updates. Indeed, even after upgrading to 23H2, it found more updates and installed them and rebooted.
- I already checked for hardware issues. As I mentioned above, the same hardware works perfectly fine on WiFi on the internet if I boot the PC with a Linux bootable USB drive. Also, if under Windows we connect an external completely different USB WiFi network adapter, completely bypassing the computer’s own internal WiFi network card, the same problem occurs. Hence, it’s not a hardware problem.
- I have already checked the WiFi network adapter settings and that the the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) option is enabled

So, Microsoft support also suggested a clean Windows install, but I explained that it would cause hardships and be time consuming. **I also told them that I think we should take advantage of this issue to study it. It's a very interesting case, very anomalous. It would be a pity to erase it by clean-reinstalling Windows, instead of dissecting it and studying it. It might lead to important insights into Windows' inner workings**.

I told them that if we analyze the behavior of the problem, we should be able to identify what Windows subsystem is causing it and to act accordingly.

For example, **Important Hints:
The fact that the problem persists also if we use an external USB WiFi network card, excludes that it's a problem of the WiFi card of the computer or its drivers.
The fact that the problem is solved if we hardwire the computer to an Ethernet cable, excludes that the whole Network subsystem is affected.
The fact that if we ping external websites via IP address in Command Prompt, excludes that it's a complete failure of the internet connection.
The fact that web browsers give the ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error message, points towards a DNS problem. As well as the fact that we can ping external websites successfully in Command Prompt
using their IP addresses, but the ping fails if we ping the same websites using their NAMES.
So, it seems to be a problem that affects Windows' DNS subsystem but only if on WiFi (regardless of what WiFi Network card we use), whereas it does not affect that 'piece' of Windows if connected via Ethernet Cable.
With this piece of information, a development Team at Microsoft should be able to point the proper subsystem that is causing this behaviour and try to fix it, maybe manually by replacing DLLs, registry keys, or other components if necessary.**

- The big boss at a Toronto IT support company I worked at when I was living in Canada, recommended the following:

*What if you put an entry in the hosts file? Does pinging by name work then?
That would imply it’s DNS that is broken but not all name resolution*

So, I tried that. Pinging by name works if I put such entries.

- oddly enough, even a simple nslookup [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) works!!!!
  But if I try to ping [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) by name, it fails

One of his colleagues and ex co-worker of mine:
*What if you specify what interface/gateway ping should use?*

And the previous:
*Can you use nslookup for any hostname and it works reliably? Like try ten different major websites and see if they all work*

oh thanks guys... Let me see...
ok so, 11 websites' nslookups work
(some of them only give me 1 address, but still something)
Specifying the gateway with ping, still fails
**it's so intriguing. I can understand that a Windows update breaks something in the networking subsystem, so DNS won't work anymore. But that it is selectively broken only if using a WiFi adapter (internal or on USB), but still works on Ethernet, really makes me curious!**

**IMPORTANT: This must mean that Windows has two distinct DNS sub-systems, one for the WiFi network (network, not 'adapter', because even using a different adapter on USB the problem persist), and one for the Ethernet network adapter.**

- Checked DNS Client service: it’s running
- Tried Use Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN): using the full domain name when pinging. For example, instead of ping [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com), try ping [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com). It still fails.
- In addition to Google’s DNS and Cloudflare’s DNS, I tried setting static OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220), still failed.
- I tried also setting a static IP for the affected computer, no change.
- I made sure Proxy is off.
- I made sure that the DNS Client service and all its prerequired services are up and running
- I also tried the usual CMD commands (flus, renew, etc.) resetting the TCP/IP stack via “netsh int ip reset” and it didn’t help. Those were actually some of the first steps I tried.
- By running the command “route PRINT -4” there was a permanent route that belonged to when we connect the computer to the corporate network via ethernet cable, showing the corporate gateway’s IP, a 0.0.0.0 mask and a 0.0.0.0 network address. I deleted that route and rebooted the PC.

**Important: Another piece of potentially useful information is the following.** The WiFi network appears to be intermittently hiccupping. Here’s what I mean. Through all these days and attempts, it kept showing this behavior: Sometimes, the Tray bar shows the little globe that appears when there is “no internet”. If I click on it, it is connected to the WiFi network but it says “no internet”. If I run Windows 11 network troubleshooter during those moments, it says there is no internet and it shows the little picture with the computer connected to the local wifi network and then the interrupted line towards the internet.
But in other moments, the little globe in the Tray bar becomes the actual WiFi bars icon. If I click on it during those moments, it shows it’s connected to the WiFi network and it says that Internet is available. If I run the troubleshooter during those moments, it exhibits 2 possible different behaviors: 1) Sometimes, it says that I am connected to the internet but that the connection has a ‘poor quality’ (I’m translating from the Italian, so I do not know the exact corresponding statement in Windows PCs that are set in English). 2) In other moments, the troubleshooter even says that I am connected to the internet and that everything is fine. But, regardless of all these different moments and behaviors, it never works. If I try to visit any website with any browser, the problem persists. If I even try to merely ping a website within CMD using the website name, it still fails.

Comment: [one can only download the Windows 11 23H2 ISO now](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=06d7c5f9-f1ce-41b0-b1be-6a6055606a88). You can download 22H2. However, that requires a fresh install, it’s impossible to do an in-place upgrade to an earlier build. You provided a lot of information but not the information needed to identify which update you actually installed. So while the ISO absolutely is available, in order to use it, would require a clean install.

Comment: You did a repair install and kept everything.  Try a repair and keep just apps. That brings you to the current version. You likely have an App issue or a User Profile issue. Keep Data keeps the  User Profile and only a fresh install is a practical fix for that.

Comment: “I tried Mobile hotspot with 3 different phones that we normally use to connect to the internet with several laptop computers, and they all work fine” - If connecting to a mobile hotspot, works, then WiFi works unless you mean you use a 4G/5G modem. Everything you describe suggests a problem with the WiFi access point

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound
Tried with traditional home routers too. No internet on WiFi.
Also, unfortunately, we cannot pinpoint the specific update, because he said he hadn't used the laptop for a long while, so he got a long stream of updates all at once. After the issue, I uninstalled all November's updates, but the problem wasn't solved. Not all updates can be uninstalled unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @John
But he didn't install any new app. The problem occurred after Windows updates.

Comment: You may have tried this already, but... Disable IPv6 completely, just in case your system thinks it can use v6 when it actually can't.

Comment: Do you use a corporate proxy?

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Yeah I tried that too :(

Comment: @Ramhound yes we use a Corporate proxy, but only on Ethernet. WiFi has none, proxy is disabled in Windows.

Comment: Make a disk image, then remove all partitions and  install Windows *de novo*. It would take less time to reinstall apps and customization from the image than all that trouble-shooting.

Comment: Ethernet and WiFI go through the same network?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks. It would be a major pain for its owner to do a clean reinstall of everything. But I suspect it's not going to work. Because a fresh Windows install disk, today, can only be created with the 23H2 version, which also includes the damaging updates already. But I'm going to try temporarily replacing the laptop's SSD with a spare drive and doing a clean Windows install over it.

Comment: @Ramhound no. Ethernet is on corporate network. WiFi was tried on the owner's router at home, and on 3 different smartphones set as hotspot.

Comment: "WiFi was tried on the owner's router at home" - So let me get this straight. Ethernet works on the corporate network I assume "in the office", while at home on their own WiFI network, the device cannot reach the internet.  Likewise, when they created a hotspot on their phone, connected to that on their laptop, the internet worked.  IF all that is true, that suggests, the problem is the home WiFi.

Comment: @Ramhound not exactly. No WiFi network works. Neither their home WiFi network, none any of the smartphones' Hotspot WiFi networks. Nothing. They also don't work if we install an external USB WiFi antenna. Nothing.

Comment: @N.DiPietro - If they created a hotspot on their phone, then connected to the hotspot over WiFi, in your question body you said hotspot WiFi worked.  "I tried Mobile hotspot with 3 different phones that we normally use to connect to the internet with several laptop computers, and they all work fine" - or are you talking about tethering?

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound
I was referring to "several laptop computers", they all work fine, they are other computers. Not the affected one. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: You were not clear enough.  You should address that fact. Although I am not entirely sure how different hardware working with a mobile hotspot is relevant to the device in question.

Comment: Make sure you've tried the troubleshooting steps here as well to reset any network settings: https://superuser.com/a/508057/673426, (though I think the network troubleshooter does most of them now). Can you clarify if connecting to the user's *home network via ethernet works too, and not only the corporate network?

Comment: Another example troubleshooting step is to see whether DNS client queries like from `ping` are showing up in Wireshark https://wiki.wireshark.org/DNS. Or try and enable the `Microsoft\Windows\DNS Client Events\Operational` log under windows event viewer application and service logs to see if it's complaining about something specific

Comment: You're right @Ramhound. I rephrased it, thanks!

Comment: Wow! Great catches @Cpt.Whale ! Thanks! Please refer to my 1st answer to this question... your input has been a game-changer!

Comment: @N.DiPietro - Here is some feedback to avoid downvotes against your question.  We are not a forum, so modifying your question to indicate the problem is solved, isn't really allowed.  If you find a solution to the problem, you should submit an answer, and then optionally accept the answer.  Edits to your question should be seamless. Adding "update   on [date here]" is just unnecessary noise and requires somebody to remove it.  Questions should be brief and to the point, but contain enough information, to answer the question.  Where that line actually exists is up to you to determine.

Comment: Based on your deleted answer, which was not an actual answer, it appears the problem is the OpenVPN configuration on the device. I would look to modify the DNS settings of the VPN connection, or just remove it entirely, as a temporary solution. In my opinion consider the problem is caused by OpenVPN I would either delete the OpenVPN keys or perform a clean install of 23H2.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound.
I am completely surprised by the deletion of my answer. Maybe I worded it too schematically (in a bullet-point form), but it was indeed the answer to the problem. The fact that 1 side-aspect (rather 'peripheral') is still uncleared, doesn't mean that my answer wasn't an answer.
I re-answered my question by re-wording my answer correctly, in a form of an answer.
About your suggestion: I was concerned about VPN already, during the initial troubleshooting steps. I had already disabled first, then completely uninstalled OpenVPN and removed its connections. The problem remained

Comment: @Ramhound I commented above answering your question about why did I add 2 answers (apparently duplicated). About your advice: Thanks, I'm more used to forums than to this platform. Thanks for your advice. I removed the 'update' edit to my question as you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

So, I do have an answer to my own question. It is an answer, as it answers to:

- Why was the "no internet" error affecting the computer (confirming the DNS problem hypothesis)
- Why weren't both standard DNS troubleshooting and unconventional DNS troubleshooting procedures working
- Why was the computer unable to surf the internet on WiFi networks, but was able if hardwired to an Ethernet connection
- Exactly what 'problem', within Windows' DNS sybsystem, was causing the issue

It also:

- Provides a solution to the main problem ("no internet" error), and to a sub-problem (DNS settings failure)
- Uncovers a defect in Windows, probably caused by a recent update, which leaves the question open (why does Windows ignore network settings and requires manual interventions in the Registry)
- Shows a root-cause analysis and a problem-solving processes that could be useful for the worldwide IT community.

##### And here is the answer:

Finally! The problem is solved, at least partially, but to a large extent. And the root-cause is also understood. So:

Enabled DNS logging in Windows Event Viewer thanks to user @Cpt.Whale and installed WireShark.

[Oddly, right after doing this, for some time, I was able to ping websites by name in CMD even on WiFi connection. But browsers were still unable to navigate any website.]

Enabling the DNS log made me notice that every DNS call kept being sent via 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.3, which are the DNS servers of the corporate network (used occasionally by the owner of the laptop at our workplace by hardwiring it via Ethernet cable). At that point, I noticed that, no matter what changes of WiFi network settings anybody made (via control panel, via Windows 11 settings, etc., setting it manually to 3rd party DNS servers, setting it back to Automatic DHCP, whatever…) it simply IGNORES any change and keeps using those corporate DNS servers. So, I searched those servers in the entire Registry and I found 4 entries that were showing 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.3. The entries are the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Dnscache\Parameters\DnsPolicyConfig\OpenVPNDNSRouting-0] "Name"=hex(7):2e,00,00,00,00,00 "GenericDNSServers"="192.168.1.1;192.168.1.3" "ConfigOptions"=dword:00000008 "Version"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{0e3f3f22-79e4-49a5-8a3b-6083a37f0d6b}] "EnableDHCP"=dword:00000000 "Domain"="" "NameServer"="192.168.1.1,192.168.1.3" "RegistrationEnabled"=dword:00000001 "RegisterAdapterName"=dword:00000000 "DhcpServer"="255.255.255.255" "Lease"=dword:00015180 "LeaseObtainedTime"=dword:656cabc3 "T1"=dword:656d5483 "T2"=dword:656dd313 "LeaseTerminatesTime"=dword:656dfd43 "AddressType"=dword:00000000 "IsServerNapAware"=dword:00000000 "DhcpConnForceBroadcastFlag"=dword:00000000 "DhcpGatewayHardware"=hex:c0,a8,01,fe,06,00,00,00,90,fd,73,a3,d5,a3 "DhcpGatewayHardwareCount"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters\DnsPolicyConfig\OpenVPNDNSRouting-0] "Name"=hex(7):2e,00,00,00,00,00 "GenericDNSServers"="192.168.1.1;192.168.1.3" "ConfigOptions"=dword:00000008 "Version"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{0e3f3f22-79e4-49a5-8a3b-6083a37f0d6b}] "EnableDHCP"=dword:00000000 "Domain"="" "NameServer"="192.168.1.1,192.168.1.3" "RegistrationEnabled"=dword:00000001 "RegisterAdapterName"=dword:00000000 "DhcpServer"="255.255.255.255" "Lease"=dword:00015180 "LeaseObtainedTime"=dword:656cabc3 "T1"=dword:656d5483 "T2"=dword:656dd313 "LeaseTerminatesTime"=dword:656dfd43 "AddressType"=dword:00000000 "IsServerNapAware"=dword:00000000 "DhcpConnForceBroadcastFlag"=dword:00000000 "DhcpGatewayHardware"=hex:c0,a8,01,fe,06,00,00,00,90,fd,73,a3,d5,a3 "DhcpGatewayHardwareCount"=dword:00000001
```

I was surprised about the persistence of “OpenVPN” stuff, since I had already uninstalled OpenVPN during the previous troubleshooting. So, first, I cleaned the registry with CCleaner and restarted the PC. The problem was still there though. But CCleaner eliminated 2 of the 4 registry entries above that had the corporate DNS servers. Then, I manually modified the remaining two other entries, swapping from 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.3 to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 and rebooted. Voilà. It worked.

For the first time in weeks now, this PC saw the light of surfing the web on a WiFi network. Finally, I re-set the WiFi adapter settings as DHCP and removed one of the two remaining 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 entries in the registry, the tcpip\parameters\interface one, leaving it blank. I kept those addresses in the remaining OpenVPN entry instead, just in case. Rebooted and it’s still working.

PARTIAL CONCLUSION (2023-Dec-05):

1. The cause of the problem seems to be the fact that Windows completely ignores whatever changes to the network and DNS settings one does. Whether you change it via control panel and then network adapter IPv4 properties, or you change it via the new System Settings menus of Windows 11, it ignores it. It stubbornly retains some old DNS settings that were set up in the past in our corporate environment. Even after several CMD reset commands, Windows Troubleshooter and network reset procedures, and even after reinstalling Windows (in-place re-install) on top of the current one.
2. The problem does NOT affect only the WiFi networks, as it seemed before. It affects both WiFi and Ethernet networks. Indeed, the user tried hard-wiring the laptop at home via ethernet cable and was still unable to navigate the web (Good question indeed, @Cpt.Whale user!). It APPEARED to be working on ethernet, because whenever I was testing the ethernet cabled network, I was doing it at our workplace, hence, the stubborn corporate DNS servers that seem to be written on stone in the soul of this PC were simply working well.
3. A mystery that now remains: Why would windows start IGNORING network settings (regardless of what one does, even performing full network resets) after some updates, to the point that one has to meddle manually in the registry? We do not have an answer to this question. Yet.

Comment: Why do you give twice the same answer?

Comment: @Toto oh, can you still see my 1st answer? A moderator deleted it. I have a note on my screen saying: "This post is hidden. It was deleted 14 minutes ago by [moderator name]" impressed over my 1st answer.
Which was actually an answer. Therefore, I re-answered my question, wording it better in an 'answer' form. I wonder why you can still see my previous answer...

Comment: @N.DiPietro Users which sufficient reputation can see deleted posts. It takes at least 10.000 rep if I remember correctly.

Comment: Interresting. I was already aware that Windows (7, 10, didn't use 8 long enough to notice and I have not seen it with 11 at all) occasionally would transfer some ipv4 settings (especially dhcp/static ip addresses) from a VPN client (observed with Cisco AnyConnect and OpenVPN) to the NIC, via which the VPN client was operating. But a simple manual correction via the GUI has always been enough to reset stuff. And it never affected DNS.

Comment: oh I see! I didn't know. Thanks @Tonny

Comment: Oh @Tonny I didn't fully understand your VPN-related comment. Could you please elaborate? I'll read tomorrow morning. Thanks. I had uninstalled OpenVPN completely during the initial troubleshooting, therefore, I thought that would have fixed any issue caused by VPN.

Comment: @N.DiPietro After using the VPN client some IP settings used in the virtual NIC of the VPN client will magically be set on the physical NIC that was previously used to make the VPN connection. These settings remain until manually removed. It is rare thing and impossible to reproduce on-demand, but working in IT support with approx 5000 of clients I have seen it happen about 5 to 10 times per year. Uninstalling the VPN client doesn't fix the problem as the wrong settings are applied on the physical NIC.

Comment: Interesting! Wow! Very good to know, thanks @Tonny
And how would I access these wrong settings in the NIC? Just by regularly opening IPv4 properties? Or does VPN affect it elsewhere?

Comment: Here is some feedback on this answer.  The formatting is absolutely horrible.  There is way to much commentary on the reason it does or does not answer your question.  As the author of the question, and the answer you find to be acceptable, it does not really matter why you find the answer to be acceptable.  You can simply submit an answer, that meets all requirements of a high quality answer, and accept the answer. Anyone that had a similar problem would be unable to use your answer.  They would be unable to import the keys, since the formatting, is non-existent.

Comment: In response to your question asking why the DNS settings from your corporate network override everything else. This is because your corporate has [set the DNS servers using a GPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1279987/changing-primary-and-secondary-dns-via-gpo). You yourself will not be able to unset this until you disconnect the PC from the corporate domain

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDavies I didn't know that.
The thing is, the acting laptop was not on the corporate domain. It was a personal laptop of an employee. He occasionally used to work remotely from home with such laptop, using a VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Ramhound

I added the 'commentary' you mentioned because, initially, I posted a similar answer but it was deleted by a moderator. The reason for deletion stated that it did not answer the the asked question(s), something like that. So, I re-posted the answer specifying why it does answer and what it answers.

The keys should 'not' be imported, because they are computer-specific! I posted them just as an example. Furthermore, I posted them in a separate box.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Windows Home part. Therefore it couldn't have been a GPO

Comment: it's okay @ChrisDavies 
On the contrary! I appreciate your input, and it might be useful in another situation.

Thank you.